# Create table in one database and design copy to multiple databases of same server automatically

Tags: sql-server, database

I have one main database in SQL Server and 5 other parallel databases on the same server. If I create / drop / alter any table in main database, those changes should be reflected in the other databases as well, automatically.

I tried it using database triggers, it's working well but sometimes it gets stuck. Can anybody provide a solution for this problem?

**My problem is I have multiple database with same structure but different data .I want If I make any structural change one database , should reflect automatically in others as well .**

Comment: I do all my create/drop/alter in a script so all I have to to is run that script on all databases. (dev/test/acceptance/production)

Comment: Can you provide more details on "Sometimes it gets stuck"? What error messages are you seeing? When does it "get stuck"? etc.

Answer (score 0):

> I want if I create / drop / alter any table in main DB

The ask can be accomlished only with some custom solution or using some high availablity solution like logshipping/Mirroring.even replication won't work

Comment: logshipping/Mirroring not allowed here . Can we do thourgh triggers like Database Trigger?

Comment: you don't havetriggers to replicate DDL

Comment: By replication , are we allowed to change definition of object or able to change Data only ?